# Docker Extension fields, environment variables and env file not mapping through

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I am trying to use environment variables and extension fields in `docker-compose` and it doesn't seem to be working.

I am starting the docker-compose with:

```
docker-compose --env-file ../.env up
```

The `.env` has:

```
DB_HOST=test_db
```

The docker-compose has:

```
version: '3.7'

x-common-variables: &common-variables
  POSTGRES_HOST: ${DB_HOST}

services:
  test_db:
    image: postgres:10.5

  application:
    build:
      context: ./app
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
```

When my application starts, it is stuck waiting on the database.
when I go into the `application` docker instance and run:

`printenv | grep POSTGRES_HOST`

it returns nothing.

Am I missing something?

Comment: An asterisk, in the last line, in the anchor reference `<<: *common-variables`?

Comment: oh oops I did have that in the code though just didn't type it in stackoverflow right